# Add images from folder to arraylist using stream

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, stream, java-stream

I'm trying to read images from a folder where the folder path is passed in as an argument, I'm trying to use the stream API to add them to the arraylist but i'm not aware what variable I should use inside the forEach() to add to my arraylist

```
    public void downsampling(String inputPath, String outputPath) {
    ArrayList<BufferedImage> inputSequence = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();

    try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(inputPath))) {
        paths
                .forEach(inputSequence.add(XXX));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

what should the XXX be replaced with? much thanks

Comment: `.forEach(x -> inputSequence.add(x));`

Comment: Worked well, thanks! <3

Comment: It’s preferable to use `inputSequence = paths.map(…).collect(Collectors.toList());`  But why collecting these images into a `List` at all? It seems, your method is supposed to process them, not return them, so just process them one by one, without adding them to a `List`.

Comment: Well yeah it's true I could've just processed them without adding them to a List but it's what came to mind at the time and it worked nevertheless, thanks tho i'll try to use your suggestion next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is incomplete as im yet supposed to do the downsampling and i've just got through the input, when i commented "worked" i meant that @Eran's comment helped me with the correct variable reference to files im streaming, here is the input code that works so far, no need to downvote me already...

```
    public void downsampling(String inputPath, String outputPath) {
    ArrayList<BufferedImage> inputSequence = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();

    try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(inputPath))) {
        paths
                .forEach(x -> {
                    try {
                        inputSequence.add(ImageIO.read((InputStream) x));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```